# How to show a power series is defined?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, power-series

One way I can think of is using radius of convergence. Since inside the interval of convergence, the series converges, i.e. not diverges to $\pm\infty$

For example I have $\cos x=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n}$, so $a_{2k}=\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}$ when $n$ is even, then $R=\lim|\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}|=\lim (2n+2)(2n+1)=\infty$, so $\cos x$ is convergent for all real numbers and therefore defined everywhere.

Is my logic correct?

Comment: shouldn't it be $R = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\displaystyle \frac{x^2}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}\right|$

Comment: You should be looking at $\lim_{x\to\infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}|$.

Answer (score 2):

You just use D'alembert test for numerical series.

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac { | \frac {(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n+2 }  }{  (2n+2)! }  |  }{|\frac {  (-1)^nx^{2n}}{ (2n)! }  |   }$$

$$=0$$

thus

> $R=+\infty$

Answer (score 2):

Your logic may be correct, but I cannot tell, so compare to this logic.

The ratio between two nonzero terms of the expansion is $R = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\displaystyle \frac{x^2}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}\right|$.

$x$ is a constant, and is the input of the function. For each $x$, as far as we are concerned when taking the limit with respect to $n$, $x$ is a constant.

Because the bottom converges to $\infty$, the ratio between two consecutive terms converges to zero.

If the ratio between terms of a power series converges to zero, then the series is convergent for all values of $x$ by the ratio test.

And if the ratio converges to a certain $R$, then the radius of convergence is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{R}$.

Comment: So convergence does imply definedness, is it correct?

Comment: Well, yes i guess